# Can I use extra/free guns to complete Uncharted on Crushing?

Tags: ps3, uncharted

I've loved both Uncharted games but haven't finished either of them on Crushing difficulty, mainly due to the crazy difficulty spikes in some of the fights. I'm wondering if I can use the free guns I've earned (that I can enable from the menu) or if this will count as cheating and stop me from finishing the game and getting the trophies.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After doing a little digging I've found that you can't use the tweaks (free guns, etc) on a difficulty you haven't already finished, so I wouldn't be able to use them anyway! I'd only be able to use them when playing Hard or below.

Comment: i was actually going to say the same thing but i wasn't sure. also most of the 'cheats' are actually disabled on crushing. I dont mean the guns, stuff like inf. ammo etc.

Answer (score 2):

In the interest of completeness, I'm posting this alternative answer which says that yes, you *can* use certain guns and cheats on difficulties you have not beaten yet. It relies on a save game glitch, and is done as follows:

1. Start a new game on the difficulty you want (Crushing, in my example)
2. Play normally until the game saves
3. Exit the game back to the main menu
4. Go into the Difficulty menu and change the game difficulty to one you've beaten (i.e., has the cheats enabled)
5. Go into the Cheats/Tweaks menu and turn on whatever you want (Inifinite Ammo, One Shot Kills are probably the most useful)
6. Go back into the Difficulty menu and change it back to what it was
7. Choose 'Continue' to load your game with the selected tweaks.

Note that because this is a glitch and not intended behaviour, it may be frowned upon by more discerning gamers! :) Doesn't block progress or trophies, though.

**edit** This glitch has only been tested in Uncharted 2. As far as I know it doesn't work with the first game.

Comment: This sounds like the save game glitch from Uncharted 2, not Uncharted 1. Are you sure this works with the first game as well?

Comment: @Kotsu you're right, thanks. I've edited my answer.